# Tensorflow protobuf incompatibility

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I could not get the tensorflow Variables to work because of protobuf incompatibility. Appreciate if someone can suggest how to fix it.

The following is the error:

```
$ python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 20, in <module>
    a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(2))
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 177, in _variable_handle_from_shape_and_dtype
    handle_data.shape_and_type.append(
AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'append'
(base) kanduru@SJC-L-00060215:/mnt/c/Users/kanduru/Documents/Courses/MIT/skunk/Auto-Surprise$
```

and the code is

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(2))
```

```
$ pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                        2.7.0
tensorflow-estimator              2.7.0
$ pip list | grep protobuf
protobuf                          4.21.1
```

Comment: Could you try with `protobuf ~= 3.19.3` and let us know?

Comment: ```
conda list | grep protobuf

libprotobuf               3.19.3               h780b84a_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  4.21.1                   pypi_0    pypi 
conda uninstall protobuf -c pypi    takes forever. It runs for days and yet doesn't finish the uninstall process.  I am unable to remove 'protobuf'
(base) root@SJC-L-00060215:~# pip remove protobuf
... 
   from pip._vendor.retrying import retry  # type: ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.retrying'

```    protobuf was installed by pip.   I am neither able to remove the package by conda or pip

Answer (score 1):

There could be an issue with the `TensorFlow` installation or `TensorFlow` version compatibility with existing libraries. `protobuf` gets installed itself with its specific version compatible to Tensorflow version while installing `TensorFlow`.
[image]

Could you please try again by upgrading the `TensorFlow` version to the latest version using the code below:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade tensorflow #or 
pip install tensorflow==2.10
```

Please have a look at this [Tensorflow install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) guide for more details.
Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Comment: I think `pip install --upgrade pip` might be the most important part of that advice.